# How can I change text content of multiple html buttons at once?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner coder trying to write a quiz with HTML, CSS, JS only. I have my first question and buttons already in my HTML document and was planning to use `replace()` method to input the new questions/answers.

Currently: when user clicks a button, `<h1>` is replaced with the new question. But now I'm unable to replace answer buttons. How do I retrieve the value of the answers from the my nested array inside of an object? Or am I doing this completely wrong?

Expected: when the user clicks an answer button, then they are presented with a new question/answer set.

```
let questionsArray = [

    {
        question: "The condition in an if / else statement is enclosed within ____.",
        choices: [
            "quotes",
            "curly brackets",
            "parentheses",
            "square brackets,"
        ],
        answer: "parentheses"
    },
    {
        question: "Arrays in JavaScript can be used to store ____.",
        choices: [
            "numbers and strings",
            "other arrays",
            "booleans",
            "all of the above",
    ],
        answer: "all of the above",
    },
    {
        question: "String values must be enclosed within ____ when being assigned to variables.",
        choices: [
            "commas",
            "curly brackets",
            "quotes",
            "parentheses",
        ],
        answer: "quotes",
    },
    {
        question: "A very useful tool used during development and debugging for printing content to the debugger is: ",
        choices: [
            "Javascript",
            "terminal/bash",
            "for loops",
            "console.log",
        ],
        answer: "console.log",
    }
]


function getQuestion() {
    //set currentQuestion from questionArray
    let currentQuestion = questionsArray[questionsArrayIndex];
    questionEl.textContent = currentQuestion.question;
    //set choices from questionArray ??
    
}


//on button click, getQuestion function will run
btnContainerEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
    getQuestion();
});
```

Comment: Probably not enough information here. Please create a [mre]. Helpful reading from the FAQ: [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets", how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992)

Comment: Loop over `currentQuestion.choices`, assigning the current choice to the corresponding button's `textContent`.